# sitefinity pluggable modules deployment without having to copy dll's

Tags: c#, asp.net, module, content-management-system, sitefinity

Here's some background.

If we want custom modules and widgets for the Sitefinity CMS, we can

1. build the module directly into SitefinityWebApp project (using thunder extension)
2. Build pluggable dll's (for both modules and widgets) and make it self installable.(here's a link on how to do this
   http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/peter-marinovs-blog/2013/03/20/creating-self-installing-widgets-and-modules-in-sitefinity)

pluggable modules can be basically copied to the bin folder on the sitefinityWebApp instance and everything will be installed automatically.

(this happens by hooking up to the PreApplication start event and installing the module and widget that we want)

Question:

What is we don't have access to the server? Can you bundle up these dll's, into a zip file and import it in the SiteFinity instance backend website? Does it unzip the file and copy all the dll's into bin directory? I guess not.

How to deploy third party modules and widgets in a sitefinity instance without having to manually copy over the dll's to bin folder?

please leave me a comment if you need more information.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to upload dlls to the bin folder via the website; as soon as you try to do so the app would restart (at least that's my understanding). the dlls would have to be uploaded via FTP RDP or some other deployment mechanism. I suppose you could upload them to a folder and load them with Reflection, but I don't think this is what you're looking for. as far as I know, dlls have to be published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would like to point out that Thunder can create an [Empty Custom Module](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/create-an-empty-custom-module) inside its own assembly, which contains the self-installing code as described in the blog post. You do not need to do it manually.

Now, about your question. Have you tried using Sitefinity Thunder's new [Code Deploy](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/code-deploy) functionality? You can use it to register them manually for you, or you can use it just to copy your assemblies over and let them register their own modules, which is the better option in my opinion. You can use the module's Install/Upgrade/Initialize methods to install or register everything which your custom module requires. Please note that Code Deploy requires you to have a Site Sync license.

If you do not have a Site Sync license, you will need to copy the assemblies manually.

Comment: This is what my understanding is as well. But given that we don't have access to the server ( and database), I dont think even site sync can help. All we have is a admin credentials for xxxCompany.com/Sitefinity. One way may be to have a seperate Admin widget which is basically a file uploader ... and through which we can upload dll's containing new modules and widgets and copy them to bin folder (ofcourse check them  to make sure they are legitimate) .. and let the dll's do the magic of self installation. Dos it sound right?

Comment: I was not talking about Site Sync. This is a new Sitefinity Thunder feature which requires the same license. If you have Sitefinity Thunder's module installed on the server, it will do pretty much the same thing. You open your local solution which contains the project with the module and you use Thunder to connect to the remote server. It will build the project, grab it's assembly and will send it to the remote server's ~/bin folder. You can do the same thing as you described but be sure to test it properly. Making changes in the ~/bin folder should cause your application to restart.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. I mixed the 2 responses that I got. Thank you that helps. But not sure if we can get the new Thunder feature if it costs more money :). Thank you for the info. And also what do you think about the approach of having a file ploader (Assembly Manager) widget that does the exact same thing as the thunder module. Actually I did a POC and it works fine ... any comments on that?

Comment: Like I said - test it properly. And keep 3 things in mind: 1) Use permissions to limit the access. You probably don't want everyone to be able to use it. 2) It might cause your application to restart. You shouldn't use it lightly on the production server, especially during rush hours. 3) It is a bad idea to use it if you use NLB because you will need to upload to every server separately. Other than that, you should be fine as long as the IIS application pool has write access to the ~/bin folder. Good luck and I hope that I was helpful! :)